# Hibernate Spring security modified design how to

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, hibernate-annotations

I'm designing a db model where I want to have:

- User(id, role_id) (UserDetails)
- Permission(role_id, permission) (GrantedAuthority)
- Role(id, description)

I'm using Hibernate and Spring security. I want every role to have list of permissions (GrantedAuthorities) using role_id rather than specific user having that. I'm kinda lost designing that. This is what I've came up with so far:

```
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "role_id", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private int roleId;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Permission> permissions;

}

public class Permission implements GrantedAuthority, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "role_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int roleId;
    @Column(name = "permission")
    private String permission;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

}
```

I've omitted the not so important code. The Role class isn't important for Spring security.

I know I'm making a huge mistake somewhere but I just can't seem to figure out how to fix it. The issue is that it joins those two objects using user.id instead of user.roleId. I've tried different annotations but I just can't hook it up correctly.

So the raw issue probably is that I'm trying to join 2 objects using a property from one and PK from another which might be a mistake.

Edit: I've also tried to specify referencedColumnName on Permission class but it didn't work either. User can't log in.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "role_id")
private User user;
```

Comment: Can you also provide the entity diagram? I dont see how the permission is mapped by User object. It should be inverse=true in the user object as permission is maintaining the relationship.

Comment: I don't have entity diagram but I'm pretty much free to change things around. It just has to work somehow. If I simply avoid annotations and set the permission list manually based on role_id the user has it works correctly.

Comment: Just forget about the code. How would you achieve a system, where user has multiple permissions based on his role? And it must work under Spring security so user has to return list of permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to have a design that can backfire you in the future? You really have to think ahead and apply good design practices on your project. This topic pops up here almost every day.

In Spring context, a role actually is an authority. I have no idea why this is made so complex by design by them. You either can have a 1) very simple approach where you assign a role which in fact is authority to an user or 2) more complex solution which includes **user**, **role** and **permission**. The idea would be to assign permissions to roles and assign roles to user. In this solution `role` entity only serves a purpose of grouping the granted permissions together as one bundle, but through your authentication manager you assign **permissions**  through **roles**.

**Note:** I am using common base `@MappedSuperclass` for my entities.

First, have an **User entity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_t")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> role = new HashSet<Role>();

    // builder/getters/setters
}
```

**Role entity**

```
@Entity(name = "role_t")

    @Column(name = "role_name", nullable = false)
    private String roleName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_permission", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id"))
    private Set<Permission> permissions;

    // getters/setters
}
```

**Permission entity**

```
@Entity(name = "permission_t")
public class Permission extends BaseEntity implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Column (name = "permission_name", nullable = false)
    private String permissionName;

    public String getPermissionName() {
        return permissionName;
    }

    public void setPermissionName(String permissionName) {
        this.permissionName = permissionName;
    }   

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return permissionName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return permissionName.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == null) return false;
        if(!(obj instanceof Permission)) return false;
        return ((Permission) obj).getAuthority().equals(permissionName);
}
```

Now in your `AuthenticationManager` or whatever you decide to use, you loop throug the roles and assign the permissions that are assigned to the roles to the user, if that makes sense.

**CustomAuthenticationProvider**

```
public class AppAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private static final String PERMISSION_PREFIX = "ROLE_PERMISSION_";
    // get the logging user info

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {


        Collection<GrantedAuthority> permissions = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (Role role : user.getRole()) {
            for (Permission perm : role.getPermissions()) {
                GrantedAuthority permission = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(PERMISSION_PREFIX + perm.getPermissionName());
                permissions.add(permission);
            }
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, permissions); // user object you get from service/repository

        return authToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to go ahead with. Role is going to be a bridge between the user and permission 'cause role doesn't concern me on permission checks in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to re-consider your schema, see the image below. work from here. You need a many-many mapping table for mapping permissions to role.

```
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", mappedBy= 'user", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private Role role;      

}

public class Permission implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "permission")
    private String permission;   
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "role_permissions", catalog = "schema", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inversJoinColumns =
            { @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)}
    private Set<Role> roles;

  }


public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "permission")
    private String permission;   
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "permission")
    public Set<Permissions> permisions;
  }
```

Update: see the new schema diagram.

[image: Updated schema diagram]

Comment: I can't have permission_id on user 'cause I want to achieve a system where user has a specific role and that role specifies what permissions user has.

Comment: Yikes, my bad, use role_id inside the user. Or create another entity role_user which has mapping of user to role.

Comment: Do I have to? Is there like no way to map it with user having role_id?

I mean user will have only one role and one role will have a list of permissions. Creating another entity just to map user to role doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: Sometimes, user can have multiple roles. He can be IT guy and HR too.

Comment: That doesn't apply here.

Comment: I'll have to adapt this a bit for our system but now I know where you're going with your answer. I'll try it out tommorow and see if I can make it work. Thanks

Comment: I've not compiled it on my system, but, this should get you going.